# How would I go about creating Textbox.Text combination WYSIWYG

Tags: javascript, asp.net

*WYSIWYG = What you see is what you get.*

**Some Info:**

Let's say I have 2 Text Boxes and one Label: **Textbox1, Textbox2, Label.**

For, let's say, a Custom ID I want to provide a text and a number. These two are combined to create the ID: Prefix + Integer.

```
Label.text = Textbox1.Text + Textbox2.Text"
```

But that is not what I'm interested in.

**The Question:**

How would I go about making a JavaScript to make "as you type" functionality to display on the result on label to show the user what their Custom ID would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you were looking for.

HTML:

```
<label id="lab">My label:</label><br><br>
Prefix: <input type="text" id="txtarea1"><br>
Number: <input type="text" id="txtarea2">
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("txtarea1").onkeyup = function() {
    document.getElementById("lab").innerHTML = document.getElementById("txtarea1").value + document.getElementById("txtarea2").value; 
}
document.getElementById("txtarea2").onkeyup = function() {
    document.getElementById("lab").innerHTML = document.getElementById("txtarea1").value + document.getElementById("txtarea2").value; 
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chris97ong/AvV8Z/1/).